# Как при отладке в eclipse выводить отладочную информацию (значения переменных) прям в редакторе кода?

Tags: eclipse, отладка, настройка

В eclipse при отладке есть возможность выводить значения переменных в каждой строке редактора кода. Какой настройкой это можно включить?

Пример, как это выглядит в pycharm

[image: пример отображения в pycharm]

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, такой возможности в `eclipse` нет. Есть возможность просматривать (и менять) значения всех находящихся в области видимости переменных в отдельном виде (`view`) `varables` (`Alt+Shift+Q, V`), можно воспользоваться видом `expressions`, который показывает значения выражений (можно, например, специально для отладки написать методы, показывающие что-то в удобном для восприятия виде), и при наведении курсора на переменную в режиме отладки отображается ее содержимое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оказалось, я видел такую реализацию в конкретной ide на базе eclipse.